# Rewrite URL in address bar for a specific page

Tags: htaccess, rewrite-rules, domain

My client has purchased a new "vanity" domain name that they want to use to forward peoplle to a specific page I've set up on their wordpress site.

I've set up web forwarding on the new domain so it's going to the right page.

e.g. www.newdomain.com   now goes to   www.wordpresssite.com/landingpage

HOWEVER, the client wants the URL in the address bar to show thw fancy new domain name - e.g. www.newdomain.com

Is there any way to achieve this using rewrite in the .htaccess file. I've tried a whole bunch of rules I've seen posted elsewhere and I'm not having any luck.

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is this any good for you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1701992/567059

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with redirect. Since, by definition, redirect sends browser off to a different location.

You would need to map domain to an actual WordPress installation. It's not hard to have WP respond to different domain requests, however in your case it's complicated that you would need it to respond *differently* conditional on domain in request.

I would say this is possible, but getting hacky. If the page in question isn't too elaborate and doesn't require any/much content management I would consider just setting it up as a separate mini-site.

Comment: Thanks for your advice - unfortunately the page in question is a dynamic content managed page relying on content from the Wordpress database. For the time being I'm using a "show in frame" option from the domain provider but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Some DNS/hosting providers offer a "show in frame" option when creating a forward in their control panel.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using a "show in frame" option at the moment - but it's not ideal for SEO purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it wih some JS utilizing the history API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history
It is supported enough to be used IMO but of course if your client insist on supporting IE6 you might need to find emulators of the API to use for older browsers.

That said, my gut feeling is that your are trying to save a dime by spending a dollar. You should just do it properly, add to your WP some code that will make it handle the new domain and show that page as the home page for it.

But most likely the best solution is to set up a totally different site, probably on a network install with domain mapping. This way you will be ble to use the WP API to extrac whatever data is needed and the landing page data will be isolated from the main site (you most likely don't want google associate it with both sites and penalize it for being duplicated content)